# can not passed for argument into awk

Tags: docker, for-loop, ubuntu, awk

I want to remove all containers at once with awk, but after running this code I got an empty line and no any argument passed to the docker.

```
for i in {1..3}; do docker container rm -f `docker ps -a | awk -v i=$i++ 'NR==i {print $1}'`; done'
```

Comment: Oops, thanks but unfortunately is not enough to solved my problem

Comment: Debug `i=1; echo $i++` in your shell first and apply that fix to `-v i=$i++`. Also, copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: thanks, http://shellcheck.net is solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

The solution you posted yourself is absurd. Just

```sh
docker ps -a -q |
xargs -n 1 docker container rm -f
```

Less compactly, you could say

```sh
docker ps -a -q |
while read -r id; do
    docker container rm -f "$id"
done
```

The `-q` option to `docker ps` causes it to only list the container's id, without the chaff you apparently figured out you wanted to remove with Awk.

Expressing shell logic as pipelines is often very succinct, natural, and quick; thinking you somehow need to know how many of something you have before you can loop over them is a rather common beginner antipattern.

If there could be more than three containers and you always want to kill the first three, you can add `head -n 3` in the obvious place; though this too seems like a potentially grave beginner mistake - you have no direct control over in which order `docker ps` will list things. A much better approach then would be to pass in a `--filter` argument to `docker ps` to select only exactly the ones which (are yours and which also) meet some filtering criterion.

Answer (score 0):

<shellcheck.net> correct my issue

thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton

```
for i in {1..3}; do docker container rm -f $(docker ps -a | awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i {print $1}'); done
```

Comment: If you run `docker ps` inside the loop and have three containers, the first time it will list three and delete the first, the second time it will list two and delete the second (which was initially the third, if they are listed in the same order), the third time it will list one and delete none. A simple fix is to print line `4-i` instead, but a much better solution is to just get the listing and loop over it.